# How to update service worker version of my subscribers?

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

i use `minishlink/web-push` for send pushes. And i make a service worker `serviceworker.js` for push messages, with `push`, `notificationclick` and `notificationclose` events listener. 
To the site where the subscription takes place a have sw.js:

```
let timeStampInMs = new Date().getTime();
importScripts('https://super-push-site.com/serviceworker.js?ts=' + timeStampInMs);
```

It works fine.

But i make a new version of service worker and place it on old place (`https://super-push-site.com/serviceworker.js`).

How to update service worker version of my subscribers without their visit to the site where the subscription takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering your question, I would like to note that it's considered a bad practice to add a cache-buster parameter to your service worker URL, since the browser will already enqueue the new service worker for installation if it's byte-different to the existing service worker. You may read more about this on: [The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#avoid-url-change)

Now, to answer your actual question:

You can manually trigger the update by calling the `update()` method of your service worker registration, when a push message is received:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    ...
    event.waitUntil(
        Promise.all([
            self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
            self.registration.update()
        ])
    );
});
```

You may also want to trigger `self.registration.update()` only if there actually is a newer version of the service worker available. To do that:

1. Store the version identifier of your SW in a variable.
2. Always send the latest SW version identifier within your push message payload.
3. Compare the two and trigger `self.registration.update()` if they don't match.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what u think about that I have no byte-different, because i change https://super-push-site.com/serviceworker.js, but not sw.js?

Comment: That would still work, as imported scripts are checked as well.

Comment: Thanks for help, Mert